# Connect to a remote host from a SSH session in Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm using Paramiko to create a SSH session to a terminal server :

```
def startSSH(strUser,strPassPhrase):    
   ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
   ssh.connect(hostname="x.x.x.x",port=9922,username=strUser,password=strPassPhrase)
```

When connection is established, I need to send a command that create a SSH session to a switch :

```
def exeCommand():
   stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ssh 10.80.3.20')
   print(stdout.readlines())
```

and then I have to type password to connect. But nothing is show on the output screen, and I don't know how to send password string using Paramiko. I also try

```
stdin.write('password')
stdin.flush()
```

but nothing happen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should set up an ssh tunnel to your "Switch" machine, and then use Paramiko to SSH through the tunnel.

For instructions on how to set up an SSH tunnel, see this link: [Transparent Multi-hop SSH](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html)
.

These StackExchange answers may also be instructive:

- [SSH into multiple remote machines through ssh tunnel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162945/ssh-into-multiple-remote-machines-through-ssh-tunnel)
- [SSH tunnel through middleman server - how to connect in one step (using key pair)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82269/ssh-tunnel-through-middleman-server-how-to-connect-in-one-step-using-key-pair)